# Untranslated messages/entries list in Symfony2

Tags: symfony, translation, yaml

I've found out that I forgot to add some of the translatations to the translations file (I'm using yaml in my project). Somehow need to find those out and add their translations, but doing that manually is quite a hassle. I wonder if there is a simpler and faster way to do such task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should install [JMSTranslationBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSTranslationBundle):

#### Overview

> This bundle puts the Symfony Translation Component on steroids. While the Translation component is highly optimized to reduce the runtime overhead of your code, it lacks a few features for translators. The aim of this bundle is to make translating a site easier while still retaining all of the performance optimizations that are currently in place.
>
> Key Features include:
>
> 1. allows developers to add additional context to translation ids to aid translators in finding the best possible translation
> 2. optimized dumping commands (nicer formatting, more information for translators, marks new messages)
> 3. optimized search algorithm (messages are found faster, and more reliably)
> 4. can extract messages for bundles, and your application (bundles) extraction configs can be set-up through
> 5. configuration to avoid having to re-type many command line arguments/options
> 6. Web-based UI for easier translation of messages

Comment: Seems like this one potentially helps: "Web-based UI for easier translation of messages". ..but it seems like that UI is only for adding and modifying translations. I wonder if it is also possible to view the list of the untranslated messages by using it (because that's my actual problem)?

Comment: You can extract messages from your app (feature #4). And then you can use web-based UI, as you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot find all untranslated messages with JMSTranslationBundle. It uses the standard Symfony way to find them. To find all, you'll need to attach a service to the logger. This way you can write untranslated Keys to the Database.

I think, this only works in dev Enviroment.

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Service;

use AppBundle\Entity\Translation;
use Symfony\Component\DependencyInjection\ContainerInterface;
use Monolog\Handler\AbstractProcessingHandler;

class TranslationLogger extends AbstractProcessingHandler
{
    protected $container;

    public function __construct (ContainerInterface $container)
    {

        $this->container = $container;
    }

    protected function write (array $record)
    {
        if ($record['channel'] === 'translation')
        {
            $em = $this->container->get('doctrine.orm.default_entity_manager');
            $check = $em->getRepository('AppBundle:Translation')->findBy([ 'transKey' => $record['context']['id'] ]);

            if (!$check)
            {
                $new = new Translation;
                $new->setTransKey($record['context']['id']);
                $em->persist($new);
                $em->flush();
            }
        }

    }
}
```

services.yml:

```
services:
    appbundle.translation_logger:
        class: AppBundle\Service\TranslationLogger
        arguments: [ "@service_container" ]
```